# How to stop downloading entire website and how to encrypt website

Tags: php, html, encryption, webserver, hosting

How can we stop download entire website. Example - WinHTTrack website copier can easily download any content of the website. So I want to stop that thing. I want to secure my website and my source codes.

Comment: please ensure you accept the answer if it helped you so others that come across it can also be helped.

Answer (score 1):

Crawlers and other software similar to WinHTTrack (such as wget) only copy what the user can see, so it's not copying your source code (the actual PHP content and database information), but rather the output (the rendered html). You can prove this by performing the same function yourself.

As it views it the same way a user can, all methods that will prevent that from happening will also prevent users from viewing it.

You can try and minimise it with things such as a [robots.txt file](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/intro), however that will only keep crawlers out that *choose* to respect it not bad actors.

It may be worth keeping information that you truly consider vital and "sensitive" behind a paywall or similar form of login to *minimise* the exposure of this kind of "attack".

Comment: _Thank you verymuch_

Comment: @ThemiyaJayakody On Stackoverflow you can say "thank you" by voting the answer up (see left of the answer) and additionally accept the answer (enable the green arrow).

Comment: @ThemiyaJayakody, if this helped you, please accept the answer.